# Page changing size on iOS when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, ios, resize

I have been having some problems with iOS (both Safari and Chrome for iOS). When the user zooms the page seems to be changing size (it is also triggering the resize javascript event dozens of times) which is messing up some of my content that is positioned using javascript. I can't fix that by binding the resize event because it's called way too many times and I have no way to know which one was the last.

I have tried setting numerous options on the viewport with no luck (width, initial-scale, maximum-scale, minimum-scale).

I have one fixed position div with fixed top, right, left and top. There are several absolute divs inside it and they have sizes and positions set in %.

It seems the page is actually changing sizes because when I zoom out after I have zoomed in I see empty borders to the right and bottom of the screen. I want to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Do you have any code we can take a look at?

Comment: @Jean-Paul The code is too big for me to post here. I can try to replicate it but I have nowhere to host it (js fiddle won't work on iPad). But I doubt I will be able to replicate it. I was hoping someone had run into this problem before, I belive it might be some random CSS rule that is causing this. I do am using twitter bootstrap though.

Comment: You can host HTML pages for free on Dropbox, just put an index.html and the related Javascript/CSS inside of the Public folder and do right click to get the public URL.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour exactly? To allow the resize and make it work consistently? Not to allow resizing at all? Moreover, have you checked that your markup is not faulty (no unclosed tags etc)?

Comment: @PaoloStefan The desired behavior is to not resize the page when zooming. The markup is correct, I'm using thymeleaf and it can not process invalid markup. It throws a big error message and stack trace if I so much forget to put a / at the end of the viewport metatag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. The page was not resizing itself, the fixed positioned elements were. It turns out the fixed positioning follows the view of the user if he zooms in. The only solution I have found is to change all my fixed positioning to absolute positioning (which in my case is going to be a pain).

I have also found that since the resize event is bound to window the view does change when zooming and so the resize function is triggered. The resize event [does not work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize) on other elements (in my case what I actually need is to see the resize on the body).

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! However I must say you made it very difficult for anyone to help, without posting any code... Next time post some more code for us to chew on. ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, it's just that the code is really big and I had no idea what was wrong, I thought it was related to some random CSS rule and not the fixed positioning itself. My CSS was way too big to put here (and some of it does not make sense without the accompanying javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a problem of that nature, even on early versions of iOS Safari/Chrome. What iOS version are you on? If you have access to OSX, have you tested Safari on all iOS versions available on iOS Simulator? Do you get the same behavior on iPad? Have you tested other browsers on small viewports? You mention something about resize events being called way too many times.

I would try to get a simple HTML page with simple styles and no javascript to work with the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

The code above should make zooming impossible... If *that* doesn't work on a simple setup, then there's definitely a bug I'm not familiar with on the iOS version you're testing on.

On the other hand, if that works, then there's something overriding the viewport tag on your code.

Comment: I have already found the problem, you can check my answer. It was not related to the viewport. I do not want to disable the zoom, I want my fixed positioned elements to not be affected by zooming. This, however does not seem to be possible.